# Update Master Workbook: Select specific sheets from multiple workbooks in parent directory

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to update named sheets in a master workbook by copying over data (as values) from other workbooks that are in different folders in the same parent directory:

The master workbook has the following sheets:
1) expenses
2) Active PL
3) Accrued Dividends

the source workbooks separately contain sheets that are named the same :
A8 - contains 'Active PL' and 'Accrued Dividends' worksheets
[A-8 source file pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYfX1.png)
H1 - contains 'expenses' worksheet
[H-1 source file pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3axtM.png)

How can I use VBA to clear the current contents of each sheet in the master, and update with the relevant data by name-checking and pulling from the source sheet accordingly from the source workbook?
[Master workbook pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpigN.png)

Comment: Look at index() with match() for one possibility

Comment: Can you throw up some screenshots of the source data sheets? What you’ve written is a little unclear to me re: the source sheets.

Comment: A-8 contains worksheets named: 'Active PL extract MTD' , 'Accrued Dividends' from which i would like to copy all and paste into the master, 'Active PL' sheet and  'Dividend' sheet

Comment: so far i'm still stuck on the opening section